# Chat in MySQL - SELECT - GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, distinct

I have these tables:

Table Name : **user_data**

```
---------------------------
| id | owner |    name    |
---------------------------  
|  1 |  120  |  "Nicolas" |   
|  2 |  140  |   "Angel"  |
---------------------------
```

Table Name : **private_messages**

```
--------------------------------------------
| id | ownerID | toUserID | message        |
--------------------------------------------  
|  1 |   120   |   140    | "Hi"           |
|  2 |   120   |   140    | "How are you?" |
|  3 |   120   |   140    | "I miss u"     |
|  4 |   140   |   120    | "Viewed."      |
--------------------------------------------
```

I need to select all rows chat for an user, for example, I have the user ID "120", I need to make a query that returns all chats that appear "120" in ownerID or toUserID.

This is my actual query:

```
SELECT
user_data.owner,
ANY_VALUE(user_data.name) name,
ANY_VALUE(private_messages.message) message
FROM private_messages 
INNER JOIN user_data ON private_messages.ownerID = user_data.owner 
WHERE private_messages.owner = "120" OR private_messages.toUserID = "120"
GROUP BY user_data.owner
```

The result to this query is:

```
----------------------------------------
| owner |    name     |    message     |
----------------------------------------  
|  120  |  "Nicolas"  |     "Hi"       |
|  140  |   "Angel"   |   "Viewed."    |
----------------------------------------
```

But if you think, this is wrong, because these two elements are from the same chat. The correct result should be the last message between both users:

```
----------------------------------------
| owner |    name     |    message     |
----------------------------------------
|  140  |   "Angel"   |   "Viewed."    |
----------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to make it?

Comment: Why you say need all chat, but then use a group by? And then your expected result is a single row? Please explain your logic a litle more.

Comment: Are these the only two users in this table, or will there be other user id's also? Maybe a little more info would be helpful....

Comment: And why do you use `OR` in the `WHERE` clause, if you need the message to belong to **both** users? You need something like `private_messages.owner = "120" AND private_messages.owner = "140"`.

Comment: Can you add more sample data using different cases and output as well?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes sorry for that, I am making the chat's notifications like Facebook, In the Facebook's Home you can see in the left corner the chat icon, so if you click there you may see the last chats with another users, but not appear all messages of each chat but appear the unique last chat. For that reason I need to get me the last messages of all chats, from the message's owner or the message's receiver.

Comment: @Kevin Yes Kevin, there are many other users in this platform.

Comment: @abcdn Yes you have reason, but that query give me only the chats that I have write, but if another user write me a message and I didn't write nothing before, the query doesn't give that chat.

Comment: @Teja Ups! I found another problem.. If I will load more chats, it continues giving me the same result.. I need to remake the query by complete. Sorry for your dedication time..

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to add another column to the table private_messages which is a conversation id, so all chats are linked to one conversation chat?

Comment: @Kevin Yes yes, we can do it, that would be a nice posibility... Thank you Kevin!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
user_data.owner,
ANY_VALUE(user_data.name) name,
ANY_VALUE(private_messages.message) message
FROM private_messages 
INNER JOIN user_data ON private_messages.owner = user_data.owner 
WHERE private_messages.touser = "120"
GROUP BY user_data.owner
```

Comment: `120` can be `touser` or `ownerid`

Comment: When adding an answer, please make sure to include your explanations, and not only code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT private_messages.id, user_data.owner,
ANY_VALUE(user_data.name) name,
ANY_VALUE(private_messages.message) message
FROM private_messages 
INNER JOIN user_data ON private_messages.ownerID = user_data.owner 
WHERE private_messages.owner = "120" OR private_messages.toUserID = "120"
GROUP BY user_data.owner order by private_messages.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

You will get one extra column. I hope you will be able to filter query to exclude id row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select u.owner, u.name, p.message
from private_messages p 
left join user_data u 
  on p.ownerid = u.owner
where p.id = (select MAX(id) id 
              from private_messages 
              where (ownerid = u.owner or touserId = u.owner) 
                and ownerid = 140 )
```

Comment: Hi Rigerta, one question, why do you use the "#" before set the table name?

Comment: Hi, sorry, that is because I created a temporary table to recreate the situation. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: What would do you good would be to have another table called chats and for each private_messages record to have a chat_id.
When two users are exchanging messages with each other all you need to keep track is of this chat_id and whenever you need to find the latest message of their chat, you will only need to check the max(id) from private_messages where chat_id will be the one these two users are having between them.